# Bound for sum of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have encountered an exercise that was quite puzzling for me. Maybe someone can help me out here?
So let $(X_n)_n $ be $N(-a,1)$ distributed, independent random variables where $a>0$. I need to prove $$P(\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} S_n > x)\leq e^{-2ax}$$
where $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. I am tempted to use Markovs inequality but the supremum kind of irritates me.
Can I somehow use that $e^{h S_n}$ is a Martingale if $h=2a$ which I proved in the first part of the exercise?

Comment: x>0 by the way.

Comment: Isn't this Doob's inequality, or else something very similar? (The point is that $S_n$ is a supermartingale.)

Comment: Yes, if you replace the supremum with a finite maximum it is quite similar. But the version I know gives a bound of the form $\frac {E[(X_n^+)^p]}{x^p}$. Not sure if this is helpful...

Comment: Well, you know the distribution of $X_n^+$, no?

Comment: So I can calculate the expectation? But what happens to the $x$ in the bottom?

Comment: The expectation doesn't depend on $x$, so the dependence on $x$ is entirely through the denominator. (That said, I do see a problem: at best this will tell you that the expectation is less than $C_p x^{-p}$, which does not give an exponential bound by itself.)

Comment: Yes that's precisely my problem! Assuming I can can calculate the expectation (which I am unsure I can because the normal distribution is very funky when it comes to positive parts...) it will depend entirely on a. But there will be an $x$ in the denominator which is not wanted if I understand the question correctly?

Comment: The $x$ in the denominator makes the bound behave qualitatively but not quantitatively like you want as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, perhaps here is the trick: $S_n+na$ is a martingale, so $\exp(S_n+na)$ is a nonnegative submartingale. Now can you imitate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Application:_Brownian_motion

Comment: Yes that's helpful! If I use that $e^{2a S_n}$  is a Martingale with expectation one this should do the trick! I will try this in a few thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $e^{2aS_n}$ is a martingale, by Doob's martingale inequality, for any fixed $N$ you have

$$P \left (\sup_{n \leq N} e^{2aS_n}>e^{2ax} \right ) \leq \frac{E[e^{2aS_N}]}{e^{2ax}}.$$

But $e^{2aS_n}$ is a martingale, so its expectation is fixed, equal to $E[e^{2aX_1}]$. This is the expectation of a lognormal r.v. where the underlying normal r.v. has mean $-2a^2$ and variance $4a^2$. Thus its expectation is $e^{-2a^2+(4a^2)/2}=1$, which gives the result up to $N$. Send $N \to \infty$ on both sides to get the desired result.